# Loading a font directly from a file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("C:/Projects/MyProj/free3of9.ttf");
```

I've tried a variety of variations and haven't been able to get it to work.

**UPDATE:**

This works:

```
PrivateFontCollection collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
collection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Projects\MyProj\free3of9.ttf");
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Free 3 of 9", collection);
Font font = new Font(fontFamily, height);

// Use the font with DrawString, etc.
```

Comment: is this path on your local ? `"C:/Projects/MyProj/free3of9.ttf"` if so it's `/` slaches need to change to `\` back slaches
"@C:\Projects\MyProj\free3of9.ttf" `public void AddFontFile(
 string filename` method

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: could you try something like this `var fontFamily = AddFontFile(@"C:\Projects\MyProj\free3of9.ttf")` if you get that working then move and or create the access level variables where needed .. i.e private, Public, Protected, static etc...

Comment: Yeah. Hate the PrivateFontCollection though. It wont work on Wine.

Answer (score 15):

This example shows how to add font from byte array - if font is stored in resources. It allows to add font from file too. Following code I am using on winforms:

It is little tricky, for loading TTF font from file you need to do this:

```
private PrivateFontCollection _privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();

public FontFamily GetFontFamilyByName(string name)
{
    return _privateFontCollection.Families.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
}

public void AddFont(string fullFileName)
{
    AddFont(File.ReadAllBytes(fullFileName));
}   

public void AddFont(byte[] fontBytes)
{
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(fontBytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr pointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    try
    {
        _privateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont(pointer, fontBytes.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really useful approach, thought the PrivateFontCollection also has a AddFontFile method to load a font from a file path. I found unconvenient in my situation to have to know the font family name in order to get it after it have been loaded. Therefore I used the following approch in the AddFont method: 1) take a copy of the _privateFontCollection.Families (let's call it before), 2) load font, 3) create a list out of the new _privateFontCollection.Families (call it after) 4) iterate each font family in before, and remove them from after. 5) return what remains in after

Answer (score 11):

This piece of code works for me (WPF):

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily(@"C:\#FONTNAME")
```

In your example, it would be:

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily(@"C:\Projects\MyProj\#free3of9");
```

The font name without the file extension, and keep the '#' symbol.

Comment: I do this exact thing in a production level project though it points to a project path instead of an absolute file path

Comment: Yes, I do the same at project level! It works in XAML files too when you define a font family in a text block in your UI, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the @user2126375`s trick as follows:

```
public PrivateFontCollection FontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
public FontFamily AddToFontCollection(string path)
    => AddToFontCollection(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
public FontFamily AddToFontCollection(byte[] fontBytes)
{
    var handle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(fontBytes, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr pointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    try
    {
        FontCollection.AddMemoryFont(pointer, fontBytes.Length);
    }
    finally
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
    return FontCollection.Families.LastOrDefault();
}
```

Enjoy...